# Xamarin.Forms Android Custom Animation not working even though it works on UWP. Ideas?

Tags: android, animation, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a custom animation that expands a Cell inside a TableView. I also refresh the tableView size before/after the animation as appropriate. This works on UWP, and I don't have a Mac yet, so I can't test it on IOS.

This doesn't work at all on Android. It does not refresh the tableRoot to update the size of it, nor does it seem to play the expanding animations.

I say the second part, because when I lock the tableview to the full size it doesn't play.

The animation itself is pretty straight forward:

```
    private void AnimateLinearRowAppear(VisualElement visual, double targetHeight = 40, TableRoot _tableRoot, bool visible)
    {
        visual.IsVisible = visible;
        TableRootRefresher(_tableRoot);
        Animation _animation;
        _animation = new Animation(
            (d) => visual.HeightRequest = d, 0, targetHeight);
        _animation.Commit(visual, "The Animation", 16, 250, Easing.Linear, (target, b) =>
        {
            _animation = null;
        });

    }
```

Any one have any ideas as to why it doesn't work on Android?

Unless I'm mistaken [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom/) is for cross platform development.

Do I have to write an interface and call each of my animations in a platform specific way?

Oh, this is the latest version of Xamarin 2.3.4.270.

Thanks for any help in advance!

I'm calling the animation from an event such as a specific picker selection or switch.

```
  Switch.toggled += (sender, e) => 
 {
     AnimationChooser(celltochange,switch.toggle,  tableRootCellIsPartOf);
  }
```

AnimationChooser decides if we're playing the appearing or disappearing animation and is working correctly.

```
private void AnimationChooser(Cell celltoChange, bool stateOfSwitch, TableRoot _tableRoot)
{
   var visual = (celltoChange as ViewCell).View
   if(visual.IsVisible && stateOfSwitch)
     { AnimateLinearRowDissappear(visual, 40 ,_tableRoot, stateOfSwitch);}
   else AnimateLinearRowAppear(visual,40,_tableRoot,stateOfSwitch);
}

 TableRootRefresher(TableRoot _tableRoot)
 {
     Var tempRoot = _tableRoot;
     _tableRoot = null;
     _tableRoot = tempRoot:
 }
```

The XAML:

```
<TableView>
  <TableRoot x:Name="root">
   <TableSection>
    <SwitchCell x:Name="switch"/>
    <EntryCell x:Name="toAppear" HieghtRequest="0" IsVisible="False"/>
   </TableSection>
  </TableRoot>
 </TableView>
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xezayq3zwy12wz8/AAAiuhKjnFVwplE52HQinnB7a?dl=0) is a sample project.

Comment: I think we'd likely need to see some code to help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I added how I'm calling the function and it's helper. Do you think a mock up of the xaml would be helpful as well?

Comment: Can you provide a sample project which can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Added a sample project. I hope it works out of the box, I had a few errors trying to upload the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below codesnippet animation working fine for me.

```
//animate changed the opacity from 1 to 0.
            //XFtabbody is my UI elements
            var animation = new Animation(v => XFTabBody.Opacity = v, 1, 0);
            Action<double, bool> finished = animate;
            animation.Commit(XFTabBody, "aa", 0, 100, Easing.Linear, finished);
        void animate(double d, bool b)
        {
            XFTabBody.Children.Clear();
    }
```